# Variable to count a certain type of objects in a list (Racket)

Tags: function, variables, racket

I have this code:

```
(define (countHearts cards)
  (let* ([count 0])
    (map (λ(x)
           (match x
             [(hearts number) (add1 count)]
             [_ #f])) cards))
  count)
```

Where cards is a list of elements in this format "(hearts number)" And when I use:

```
(countHearts '( (hearts 1) (hearts 2)))
```

It returns (the answer should be 2):

```
#<procedure:count>
```

All I want is that my code counts the number of "(heart number)" (a type previously defined) that I have in a list, but I keep getting that answer. Does anybody have an idea? I have tried other options besides add1 like

```
!set count (+ count 1)
```

But the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(define (count-hearts cards)
  (for/sum ([card cards])
    (match card
      [(list 'hearts n) 1]
      [_                0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

**why your code doesn't work**

1. `(add1 count)` adds 1 to count but throws the result away; you need to `set!` count to the result of `(add1 count)`
2. You had a closing parenthesis too many so your variable `count` got out of scope and you returned the build-in procedure `count` - count needs to be returned inside the `let*` or `let` expression (I use `let` since that's sufficient here)
3. FWIW, both your and @soegaard's code don't work for me and return "match: syntax error in pattern"; I modified the `match` expression to `(list 'hearts _)`

So the code becomes:

```scm
(define (countHearts cards)
  (let ([count 0])
    (map (λ(x)
           (match x
             [(list 'hearts _) (set! count (add1 count))]
             [_ #f]))
         cards)
    count))
```

then

```scm
> (countHearts '((hearts 1) (hearts 2)))
2
```

**alternative**

You could use the build-in `count` procedure:

```scm
(define (countHearts cards)
  (count (lambda (e) (eq? (car e) 'hearts)) 
         cards))
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see the problem is that when you use the input (countHearts '((hearts 1) (hearts 2))) you need to use (list 'hearts _) for matching, while using (countHearts (list (hearts 1) (hearts 2))) you can use (hearts _)